# Reinstall SQL Server using different language

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a VM with SQL Server 2012 installed, but it looks like a German installation as most of the programs in the start menu for it are in German (Daten importieren und exportieren for example). I've downloaded the ISO package for the English version, but I'm not sure how to "reinstall" everything to use the English version.

I don't want to completely uninstall the existing installation as there are databases in there I need. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you simply reinstall SSMS and other client tools. Databases can have the language changed without additional installations.

Comment: You can side-install the latest version of SSMS (v17 or v18) in the language you want. SSMS is not part of the SQL Server installation anymore.

Comment: It's not just SSMS though, it's all of the additional tools. Daten importieren und exportieren instead of Import and Export Data for example. That one is bundled with SQL Server and I can't uninstall separately